# Scala: using hasmap as constructor

Tags: scala, parameters

Why does the compiler complain at this? I do believe java was fine with this.

```
class myClass(rules:Map<String,Boolean>) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala Type arguments must be written in square brackets:

```
class myClass(rules: Map[String,Boolean])
```

Comment: Ah. I see. Thank you. Looks like people didn't really appreciate my confusion.. hah..

Comment: @Shelby.S Because such things are written in first half of any book on Scala

Comment: Sorry, I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not "should" as in a recommendation. It's *must* as in a requirement. It's the only way. Period.